# SSD available in diskpart, not available in Windows 11 installation

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd, windows-installation

I am building a dual boot setup on an NVMe SSD.

The SSD shows up in `diskpart` and can be accessed and formatted from there, but is not available as an installation target.

I'm using `diskpart` from the command shell available from the Windows installer (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> in the installer screen). I am booted from the Windows 11 installation USB stick.

Because it is visible in `diskpart`, my assumption would be that driver support is not the problem here and I can disregard the advice about using AHCI emulation mode to allow an in-box driver to attach to it.

Is there an additional filter that excludes PCIe NVMe disks as installation targets even if they otherwise work?

Are there requirements on the partition table to allow the Windows installer to operate? (I have: GPT with protective MBR, 500 MB ESP, 250 GB Linux LVM partition, remainder of space unallocated.)

Comment: In which OS are you using diskpart and how are you booting to it?

Comment: I'm using diskpart from the command shell available from the Windows installer (Shift-F10 in the installer screen). I am booted from the Windows 11 installation USB stick.

Comment: Please also explain your dual boot setup. If you have formatted the disk using diskpart, how did you do it?

Comment: If you want to setup a dual-boot system with Windows, install Windows FIRST, starting with a really empty disk. Doing it the other way around is not recommended, because Windows fully expects to be the only OS on the system and will happily bork anything else while installing. Or refuse to install at all (as you just discovered).

Comment: If your disk is not discovered within the Windows installation environment it means, while it’s booted in UEFI, your disk is formatted as MBR or vice versa your booted in CSM and your disk is GPT.  Windows 11 has all necessary drives to automatically detect your drive built-in so that’s the only explanation